# Using subprocess.run to convert a file to one type to another

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, ghostscript

I have the following python instruction:

```
subprocess.run('gswin64c -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pngalpha -sOutputFile=C:/Users/ingNC/Desktop/results/Sub-frame4.png C:/Users/ingNC/Desktop/test/Sub-frame4.ps', shell=True, check=True, text=True)
```

I have the .ps file 'Sub-frame4.ps' and I want to convert this file in a .png file named 'Sub-frame4.png ' and save the latter in the folder 'results'. Will I need to create the file 'Sub-frame4.png', before running the instruction? Or this file will be created during the execution of the command?

Answer (score 0):

The ghostscript command will create the file.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to run this command in a python file, and I get an exit status1. So, I tried: gswin64c -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pngalpha -sOutputFile=C:/Users/ingNC/Desktop/results/Sub-frame4.png C:/Users/ingNC/Desktop/test/Sub-frame4.ps  in a command prompt, and I get an error message " 'gswin64c' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file ". Since ghotscript is an intern module of python, I don't understand what the point is. Please, do you have an idea?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "ghostscript is an interim module of Python". Ghostscript is an executable. Have you actually installed Ghostscript ? Have you added the Ghostscript path to your $PATH environment variable.